# what is the best way to create dynamic html table in asp.net mvc?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, foreach, html-table

My question is that "what is the best way - in concept of efficiency- to create dynamic table in html for Asp.net Mvc project"?

On the other hand can i create dynamic table in html for Asp.net Mvc project with foreach loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> what is the best way to create dynamic table in html

"Best way" is a very subjective term.  But one simple approach would be exactly what you propose...

> can i create dynamic table in html for Asp.net Mvc project with foreach loop?

Of course.  Assuming you have a collection of some kind on your view model, you'd simply loop over that collection and emit values from it.  Something as simple as this:

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in model.SomeCollection)
{
    <tr><td>@item.SomeValue</td></tr>
}
</table>
```

All the code is doing is iterating over a collection of items and emitting markup and values for each element in that collection.